# How to submit a form in Angular and send data back?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm building a form component to get some data from user and send them back to another component, which has to be updated according to these values.

In my code I have two components: 
1) Balance page
2) Balance-add component
I'd like Balance page to be updated every time the user fills the form in Balance-menu component, and I need to create a new card in the Balance page for each form submitted.

Balance.page.ts:

```
constructor(
  private router: Router,
  ) { }

ngOnInit() {
  }

addToList() {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('balance-add')
}
```

balance.page.html:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>Balance:</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <div>
        {{this.balance}}
      </div>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>

//Here <ion-card> for each form submitted 
//<ion-card *ngFor="let form of list_of_forms"></ion-card>


</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <div>
    <ion-icon name="add-circle" (click)="addToList()"></ion-icon>
  </div>
</ion-footer>
```

The second component is balance-add.component.ts
(I don't know how to implement sendData method)

```
constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {}

sendData() {
// ???
}
```

and here's the html:

```
<div>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>How much did you spend?</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="buy.cost" okText="Okay" cancelText="Dismiss">
    <ion-select-option value="ten">10</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="twelve">20</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>What is the item?</ion-label>
  <ion-input [(ngModel)]="buy.item" placeholder="E.g. Eggs></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

<ion-button (click)="sendData()"> ADD TO BALANCE </ion-button>

</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: You can share your data between components using four ways refer this https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Comment: @SnehaPawar or [use the official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) instead of paying resources ! (well not this page, but you get my point)